# Prove: The number of elements $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ with $\langle a\rangle=\langle d\rangle$ for some $d\mid n$ is $\varphi(\frac{n}{d})$

Tags: group-theory

This is a homework assignment in an undergrad group theory course.

Proposition: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $d\mid n$. Then $$\left|\left\{ a\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}\mid\left\langle a\right\rangle =\left\langle d\right\rangle \right\} \right|=\varphi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$

Where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's phi function, counting the number of coprimes of $n$ that are no greater then $n$

I'd like to show that for $a\in\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ we have $\left\langle a\right\rangle =\left\langle d\right\rangle \iff\gcd\left(a,\frac{n}{d}\right)=1$.  I have tried many ways and have failed to prove either direction. This is the first part of a multi part qusetion, so I get the feeling there should be a simple solution which I am missing.

Edit (answer): I ended up showing that $\left\langle d\right\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$ and since there are excactly $\varphi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$ elements that generate $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$, the isomorphism gives the same for $\left\langle d\right\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $<d> = \{d, 2\cdot d, 3\cdot d,.... \frac nd\cdot d=e\}$  And $<a> = \{a, 2\cdot a, ....., m\cdot a = e\}$. if $<a> = <d>$ then $m = \frac nd$ and $a \in <d>$ so $a = k\cdot d$ for some integer $k; 1\le  k \le \frac nd=m$.  Likewise $d \in <a>$ so there is some integer $j$ where $d = j\cdot a = j\cdot k \cdot d$ and $j\cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

Given a $k$ and $m$, $j\cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod m$ will have solutions if and only if $k$ and $m$ are relatively prime.

So there are $\phi(m) = \phi(\frac nd)$ possible values of $k; 1\le k \le \frac nd$ for which $a = k\cdot d$ and $<a> = <k\cdot d> = <d>$.

Comment: I don't follow. Why does $\langle a \rangle = \langle d \rangle $ imply that $m = \frac{n}{d}$? Also, why is $d=n\cdot a$? surely you mean $d = l\cdot a $ for some $l$? Thank you for your help

Comment: We are told $d|n$ so $<d>$ contains $d, 2d,3d,$ etc. up to $\frac nd*d=n\equiv 0\pmod n$.   Now $<a>$ contains $a, 2a,3a$ etc up to $\frac ma\equiv 0\pmod n$ .  But if $<a> = <d>$ then they must have the same number of elements.  $<d>$ has $\frac nd$ elements an $<a>$ has $m$ elements ($m =\gcd(n,a)$ BTW).  So $m = \frac nd$.

Comment: $d = na$ was a brain fart.  Seeing as we were dealing with values $\frac nd = m, a,$ and $d$ the value $n$ was no longer important.  So I forgot the variable $n$ was already used.  I mean $n$ to be a new variable value.

Comment: EDIT: We are told $d|n$ so $<d>$ contains $d,2d,3d$, etc. up to $nd∗d=n≡0(modn)$. Now <a> contains $a,2a,3a$ etc **up to $ma\equiv0\pmod n$** .... Sorry,  the $\frac ma \equiv 0 \pmod n$ in the above comment should have been $ma \equiv 0 \pmod n$.